# Developing website front-end on Mac with Asp.net MVC back-end

Tags: php, asp.net, web-applications

I am an Asp.net back-end developer who uses Visual Studio on Windows and I work with a front-end team who all use Macs.  I'm trying to workout the best way for us to work together without me having to repeatedly integrate the front-end into the Asp.net site.  i.e Manually add the front-end changes into the *.csHTML views

I'm proposing to....

- Ditch using Asp.net MVC Views all together and just let the front-end team build the web pages as plain old *.htm  files, like a static website build
- Any communication from front-end to the back-end is done via Ajax calls.  So while they are developing on Mac they can point the Ajax calls to the back-end on a Windows box.  This will essentially make the Asp.net site just a Web service site.
- Any configuration settings that need to be pulled through to the front-end from the back-end  is done via Ajax calls.

Note-
Our sites will only ever support javascript enabled browsers (I know it's not ideal but that's the situation i'm in).

Are there any glaring issues you can see by developing Asp.net sites this way?  I

'm feeling like this a new trend in web development in general, as the front-ends become more and more rich and ajax heavy.

I guess this isn't a Asp.net specific question, as it could be applied to web language ike PHP.

Comment: You might also consider front-end build tools like HAML.

Comment: Would a framework like knockout be a possibility?  Would match your second bullet point.